# Как использовать casperjs в nodejs?

Tags: node.js, casperjs

Пишу

```
const casper = require('casperjs');
```

при выполнении node index.js получаю ошибку

Error: Cannot find module 'casperjs'

Как его использовать?
Или может есть модули для nodejs аналогичные касперу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гугл подсказал копать в этом направлении
https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS

вроде как работает, попробовал waitSelector, capture.